# How can I generate a licensed download link in azure storage blob

Tags: java, azure, download, blob, azure-blob-storage

I can get a link by those code, and it could download a file successfully.

```
BlobContainerSasPermission blobContainerSasPermission = new BlobContainerSasPermission()
                .setReadPermission(true)
                .setWritePermission(true)
                .setListPermission(true);
BlobServiceSasSignatureValues builder = new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(1), blobContainerSasPermission)
                .setProtocol(SasProtocol.HTTPS_ONLY);
BlobClient client = new BlobClientBuilder()
                .connectionString("connection string")
                .blobName("")
                .buildClient();
String blobContainerName = "test";
return String.format("https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s?%s",client.getAccountName(), blobContainerName, client.generateSas(builder));
```

but everyone could download the file by this link, I want the file could be downloaded by the one who is authorized. Is there any code or azure's setting(such as AD?) could implement this? Thanks

-------------------------update------------------------

I find a [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.blobserviceasyncclient.getuserdelegationkey?view=azure-java-stable),and there gives a reason.
**Note: This method call is only valid when using TokenCredential in this object's HttpPipeline.**
but there is only *BasicAuthenticationCredential* which implements *TokenCredential* in my imported package. This is my mvn.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
    <version>12.11.0-beta.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And I tried this

```
String userName = "userName";
String password = "password";
BasicAuthenticationCredential basicAuthenticationCredential = new BasicAuthenticationCredential(userName,password);
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().endpoint(endpoint).credential(basicAuthenticationCredential).buildClient();
```

then I got this **Status code 401, (InvalidAuthenticationInfo)**

Gods, help me!

Comment: Do take a look at User Delegation SAS here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no way to implement this.

[This is the answer.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/21627#issuecomment-847229635)

Answer (score 1):

> A SAS token for access to a container, directory, or blob may be
> secured by using either Azure AD credentials or an account key. A SAS
> secured with Azure AD credentials is called a user delegation SAS.
> Microsoft recommends that you use Azure AD credentials when possible
> as a security best practice, rather than using the account key, which
> can be more easily compromised. When your application design requires
> shared access signatures, use Azure AD credentials to create a user
> delegation SAS for superior security.

**Generating SAS query parameters with `UserDelegationKey`**

The following sample generates SAS query parameters for an Azure storage container.

```
BlobSasPermission blobPermission = new BlobSasPermission()
    .setReadPermission(true)
    .setWritePermission(true);

// We are creating a SAS to a container because only container name is set.
BlobServiceSasSignatureValues builder = new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues()
    .setProtocol(SasProtocol.HTTPS_ONLY) // Users MUST use HTTPS (not HTTP).
    .setExpiryTime(OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(2))
    .setContainerName("my-container")
    .setPermissions(blobPermission);

// Get a user delegation key after signing in with Azure AD
UserDelegationKey credential = new UserDelegationKey();
String account = "my-blob-storage-account";
BlobServiceSasQueryParameters sasQueryParameters = builder.generateSasQueryParameters(credential, account);
```

Check out [Create a user delegation SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas) and [this](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-storage-blob/12.0.0/com/azure/storage/blob/sas/BlobServiceSasSignatureValues.html) for implementation details.

Comment: I have tried this 

but I got a exception at the last line --> Only authentication scheme Bearer is supported

Comment: `OffsetDateTime expiryTime = OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(1);
BlobSasPermission permission = new BlobSasPermission().setReadPermission(true);
BlobServiceSasSignatureValues values = new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(expiryTime, permission).setProtocol(SasProtocol.HTTPS_ONLY).setStartTime(OffsetDateTime.now());
UserDelegationKey userDelegationKey = blobServiceClient.getUserDelegationKey(OffsetDateTime.now(),expiryTime);`

Comment: Status code 403, "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:6c4b7821-b01e-0022-07c7-4b94e5000000
Time:2021-05-18T09:20:28.9329978Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Only authentication scheme Bearer is supported</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>"

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: It seems the SAS is not created correctly

Comment: You are incorrectly writing the code, pls check my updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much, but it seems that my imported package is different with yours. This is my dependency, '<groupId>com.azure</groupId><artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId><version>12.11.0-beta.2</version>', in this version , the class `BlobServiceSasQueryParameters` is Deprecated, and prefer to use `BlobServiceSasSignatureValues`

Comment: `BlobServiceSasSignatureValues` is only used above.

Comment: Thank you so much, please check my updated question. It seems that there is no way...